# Unable to connect to Zalenium service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, zalenium

Unable to connect to `Zalenium` service from my Kubernetes cluster:

I am trying to get the external IP of the `zalenium` service that I have created via my Kubernetes cluster. I am getting the following :

```
$ kubectl get services --namespace zalenium
NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
zalenium   NodePort   172.21.187.0   <none>        80:30190/TCP   58m
```

Can anyone help me how to get the EXTERNAL-IP please?

Comment: Which cluster are you using or trying? Is it minikube cluster or GKE or Azure or AWS or something others?

Comment: I agree with @ShudiptaSharma and you should also post the output of `kubectl -n zalenium -o yaml svc` because (for clarity) a `Service` of type `NodePort` will not acquire an external IP -- only a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` will do that

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma I am using IKS cluster

Comment: Hi @MatthewLDaniel, I am posting you the output of the yaml of the Zalenium service for your easy reference purpose:"spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "hub",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 4444,
        "nodePort": 30190
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "zalenium",
      "app.kubernetes.io/name": "zalenium"
    },
    "clusterIP": "172.21.187.0",
    "type": "NodePort",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }

Comment: Hi @MatthewLDaniel, can you please what changes I need to do here please so that I can get the External-IP....thanks

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, use [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58351510/edit) to update your post. As I mentioned, `NodePort` services do not assign themselves any external IP because that's not their job. If you want an external IP, use a service of type `LoadBalancer`. Right now, **every** Node in your cluster is listening on port 30190 and forwarding traffic to every Pod that matches that selector

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, can you kindly show with some example please how to achieve the same? Tnx.

Comment: @Sayom please provide output of `kubectl get svc zalenium -n zalenium -o yaml` and add it to your question. Also did you use `kubectl expose` or just used yaml?

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, here is the output:                                                        spec:
  clusterIP: 172.21.187.0
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: hub
    nodePort: 30190
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4444
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: zalenium
    app.kubernetes.io/name: zalenium
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, any updates on this please?

Comment: Hi All,Any update on this issue please?